# Disable Word Online platform when publishing office js application to store

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins, office-store

Is it possible to publish office js Word plugin for Word 2016+ but not for Word Online platform?

Comment: What technology are you intending to do this with?

Answer (score 1):

All apps and add-ins submitted to the Office Store must comply with the Office Store Validation Policies Specifically section [4.12.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies), "Your add-in must work across all platforms that support the methods that you define in the Requirements element in your add-in manifest."

For details about which platforms support which methods, see [Office Add-in host and platform availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability).